# How should the Albanian "genitive" really be analysed?

Tags: syntax, cases, albanian

The Albanian language is typically described as having a genitive case. In actuality, this "case" consists of an connective particle which agrees in number, gender AND CASE with the preceding head noun, followed by the noun denoting what is possessed in the dative case. So for example:

> libri i njeriut "the book of the man" (connective particle i for m.sg.nom.)
> Unë shoh librin e njeriut "I see the book of the man" (e for m.sg.acc.)
> pranë librit të njeriut "near the book of the man" (të for m.sg.abl.)

How is it possible for a "case" to be inflected for case???

It would make more sense to mentally translate the connective particle as "which [is/are]...", as follows:

> libri i njeriut "the book (nom.) which (nom.) is to the man" (i.e. which is possessed by the man)
> Unë shoh librin e njeriut "I see the book (acc.) which (acc.) is to the man."
> pranë librit të njeriut "near the book (abl.) which (abl.) is to the man"

This construction is paralleled by the treatment of postnominal adjectives, e.g.

> libri i mirë "the good book" (i.e. "the book (nom.) which (nom.) is good")
> Unë shoh librin e mirë. "I see the good book."
> pranë librit të mirë "near the good book"

Is there a standard analysis that treats the genitive as a CONSTRUCTION rather than as a "case", and if so, what is the standard term for what I'm calling a "connective particle" here?

Comment: "followed by the noun denoting what is possessed" -- shouldn't this be "followed by the noun denoting the possessor"?

Comment: You are correct. Good catch.

Comment: Almost the exact same thing happens [in Romanian as well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balkan_sprachbund): *carte a (cartea) omului, carti ale (cartile) omului*, with the genitival articles *a, ai, al, ale* corresponding in number and gender with the possessed object, and the (genitival) form of the possessor being indistinguishable from that of its dative case.

Answer (score 2):

See A. Spencer, [The possessum-agreement construction  or  'Does Albanian have a
genitive case?'](http://repository.essex.ac.uk/119/1/ERRL53.pdf). He says

> they are precisely homologous to the
> possessive  construction  of  Bantu  languages.  This  construction,
> the   ‘possessum-agreement’ construction, marks the possessor noun or
> noun  phrase with a formative which agrees with the possessor in the
> manner  of an adjective, but the possessum itself is not categorially
> an adjective  and  the  possessum  phrase  itself  retains  the
> internal  syntax  of  a  noun   phrase.

("they" because Hindi has the same construction).

Comment: Isn't "agrees with the possessor" in the cited passage an error for "agrees with the possessum"?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I got them backwards.